# How to run SSIS package from point of failure in next run without using Checkpoint

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I have a ssis package which have more than 10 tasks. I maintain sql table as success or failure for each task. I need to design my pkg in such a way when It fails and we run it next time, It should check the sql table and pick the task which got failed and It should execute from the failed task, But not from starting.

I do not want to use checkpoint. How can we achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Can Someone please suggest on this? Thanks

Comment: Use expressions to selectively disable tasks based on what is in your table

Comment: Thanks Nick, But how to enable it again for the further runs?

Comment: Your management framework should reset everything in the SQL table once the package runs correctly to completion. So you'll need a "success" step at the end to reset it. That's why I don't really like implementing these things because it requires more logic, and more things can go wrong.

Comment: Unless there is a issue with duration, you're much better off designing the work to be _idempotent_. That is, you can run any step at any time and it won't "double up" the output.

Comment: Yeah But once we complete it, How can we Enable the task which we have dynamically disabled in package because we have disable property, But do not have anything to enable the task. Please correct me If I am wrong. Thanks.

Comment: This looks like an example of what you're after, except that your SQL statement should look in your control table rather than looking for an actual table. http://bi-polar23.blogspot.com/2008/02/expressions-and-precedence-constraints.html. You just need to set the values in the control table as your tasks complete, say to "Completed".  Then when all tasks are complete you set all control rows to "Ready"